# Accepted answer to my question deleted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer

A while back I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131394) and quickly got an answer that resolved it completely (and so I accepted it). If I recall correctly, it was the perfect pair of question and answer for the site, because it was a cryptic and very specific error that had a very, very simple but unthinkable solution. So as a documentation, this would help a handful of people to save several hours if not days each.

Recently, I've gotten a couple of upvotes on my question, meaning that indeed it is a common problem sought by other people. However, I went to check and found out that the answer was gone, probably deleted.

So I decided to answer it myself with the knowledge I learned, but:

- I don't know if it was the proper thing to do in this situation.
- I was wondering what could've happened to get a perfectly good (as far as I recall) answer deleted. If there was any problem, it could've been edited.

Also, bonus questions: Shouldn't an asker get notified if the accepted answer for his question was deleted? And shouldn't he be able to see it, even after that? I mean, imagine my frustration if I hadn't recalled the answer and had the same problem again!

Comment: The answer is not an answer, but a comment. And the comments of that answer contain the real answer which fixed your problem. The answer was deleted by a mod, so he probably deleted it as a response to a NAA flag (, and I think they don't see the comments in the flag queue).

Comment: @Rizier123 as I said, I don't recall exactly how it happened, because I can't see the history of the question, but I indeed remember there was some sort of in-comment discussion. If this was the case, shouldn't the answer be edited to contain the info that was in the comment and solved the question? Should I've done that? Or should've the mod?

Comment: @LuanNico I have edited the comment content and a proper attribution into your answer; as you didn't write the answer, you could consider making it a community wiki.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the edit! I didn't know about this feature, but just converted the answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer into the actual answer. So potentially it can be undeleted and the right person credited. But that would require a moderator to do so.